# Connecting infoPath form with SQL server in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, infopath

I have an BCS/external content type in SPD connected to my InfoPath form.

I want to insert the data to the SQL table. Therefore, I have the following rules:

R1) Query using a data connection: Main connection

R2) Insert field value for insert/submit command I used in the value field the following sql query

```
concat("ExecuteSqlQuery /dsname=SQLserverNameHere /sql=set DBnameHere off" 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[DBtableNameHere] ([ID], [First Name], [Last Name]) 
       VALUES @ID, @FirstName, @LastName)
```

I would really appreciate as much detail and help as possible; thank you!